# I need the results of 7 day period and sum all point according to 7 day

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

```
USE [MLMDB]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[payoutPoints]    Script Date: 10/15/2015 16:58:43 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[payoutPoints](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [userid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [payoutBatchId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [points] [int] NOT NULL,
    [pointPosition] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [forUserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [insertDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_payoutPoints] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ON
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (371, 4, 36, 1, N'R', 149, CAST(0x0000A51500000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (372, 4, 36, 1, N'L', 205, CAST(0x0000A52801151D79 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (373, 149, 36, 1, N'R', 206, CAST(0x0000A528011564D6 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (374, 4, 36, 1, N'R', 206, CAST(0x0000A528011564D6 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (375, 149, 36, 1, N'L', 207, CAST(0x0000A528011661F3 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (376, 4, 36, 1, N'R', 207, CAST(0x0000A528011661F3 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (377, 206, 36, 1, N'R', 208, CAST(0x0000A5280116FFDF AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (378, 149, 36, 1, N'R', 208, CAST(0x0000A5280116FFDF AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (379, 4, 36, 1, N'R', 208, CAST(0x0000A5280116FFDF AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (380, 4, 36, 0, N'M', 209, CAST(0x0000A528011736D0 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (381, 205, 36, 1, N'L', 210, CAST(0x0000A5280117E487 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (382, 4, 36, 1, N'L', 210, CAST(0x0000A5280117E487 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (383, 208, 37, 1, N'R', 211, CAST(0x0000A52900BEA5D5 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (384, 206, 37, 1, N'R', 211, CAST(0x0000A52900BEA5D5 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (385, 149, 37, 1, N'R', 211, CAST(0x0000A52900BEA5D5 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (386, 4, 37, 1, N'R', 211, CAST(0x0000A52900BEA5D5 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (387, 211, 37, 1, N'R', 212, CAST(0x0000A52900BF2493 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (388, 208, 37, 1, N'R', 212, CAST(0x0000A52900BF2493 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (389, 206, 37, 1, N'R', 212, CAST(0x0000A52900BF2493 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (390, 149, 37, 1, N'R', 212, CAST(0x0000A52900BF2493 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (391, 4, 37, 1, N'R', 212, CAST(0x0000A52900BF2493 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (392, 207, 37, 1, N'L', 213, CAST(0x0000A52900BFB6A6 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (393, 149, 37, 1, N'L', 213, CAST(0x0000A52900BFB6A6 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (394, 4, 37, 1, N'R', 213, CAST(0x0000A52900BFB6A6 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (395, 212, 37, 1, N'R', 214, CAST(0x0000A52900C1DE11 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (396, 211, 37, 1, N'R', 214, CAST(0x0000A52900C1DE11 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (397, 208, 37, 1, N'R', 214, CAST(0x0000A52900C1DE11 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (398, 206, 37, 1, N'R', 214, CAST(0x0000A52900C1DE11 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (399, 149, 37, 1, N'R', 214, CAST(0x0000A52900C1DE11 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (400, 4, 37, 1, N'R', 214, CAST(0x0000A52900C1DE11 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (401, 214, 37, 1, N'R', 341, CAST(0x0000A52900D41D22 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (402, 212, 37, 1, N'R', 341, CAST(0x0000A52900D41D27 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (403, 211, 37, 1, N'R', 341, CAST(0x0000A52900D41D27 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (404, 208, 37, 1, N'R', 341, CAST(0x0000A52900D41D27 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (405, 206, 37, 1, N'R', 341, CAST(0x0000A52900D41D27 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (406, 149, 37, 1, N'R', 341, CAST(0x0000A52900D41D27 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (407, 4, 37, 1, N'R', 341, CAST(0x0000A52900D41D27 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (408, 210, 37, 1, N'L', 358, CAST(0x0000A52900D50328 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (409, 205, 37, 1, N'L', 358, CAST(0x0000A52900D50328 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (410, 4, 37, 1, N'L', 358, CAST(0x0000A52900D50328 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (411, 4, 37, 1, N'R', 358, CAST(0x0000A53100D50328 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (412, 4, 37, 1, N'R', 358, CAST(0x0000A53100D50328 AS DateTime))
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] OFF
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[incentiveReport]    Script Date: 10/15/2015 16:58:43 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[incentiveReport](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [userid] [int] NULL,
    [totalbal] [float] NULL,
    [UseBal] [float] NULL,
    [payoutBatchId] [int] NULL,
    [tdsPer] [float] NULL,
    [adminchargePer] [float] NULL,
    [TotalTdsAmount] [float] NULL,
    [TotalAdminAmount] [float] NULL,
    [dateTime] [date] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_incentiveReport] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[incentiveReport] ON
INSERT [dbo].[incentiveReport] ([id], [userid], [totalbal], [UseBal], [payoutBatchId], [tdsPer], [adminchargePer], [TotalTdsAmount], [TotalAdminAmount], [dateTime]) VALUES (3, 4, 200, 180, 36, 0, 10, 0, 20, CAST(0x833A0B00 AS Date))
INSERT [dbo].[incentiveReport] ([id], [userid], [totalbal], [UseBal], [payoutBatchId], [tdsPer], [adminchargePer], [TotalTdsAmount], [TotalAdminAmount], [dateTime]) VALUES (4, 149, 0, 0, 36, 0, 10, 0, 0, CAST(0x833A0B00 AS Date))
INSERT [dbo].[incentiveReport] ([id], [userid], [totalbal], [UseBal], [payoutBatchId], [tdsPer], [adminchargePer], [TotalTdsAmount], [TotalAdminAmount], [dateTime]) VALUES (5, 149, 200, 180, 37, 0, 10, 0, 20, CAST(0x843A0B00 AS Date))
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[incentiveReport] OFF
/****** Object:  Default [DF_incentiveReport_dateTime]    Script Date: 10/15/2015 16:58:43 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[incentiveReport] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_incentiveReport_dateTime]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [dateTime]
GO
```

> my ans (i get daily report but cant get report according to  7 day )

```
USE [MLMDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[WeeklyResult]    Script Date: 10/16/2015 11:01:22 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

 /*
 EXEC [WeeklyResult] @UserID = 4;
 */

 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[WeeklyResult]
  @UserID INT
AS
begin


     IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#result') IS NOT NULL
     DROP TABLE #result

   create table #result
      (
       date varchar(max),
       Left_Point int,
       Right_Point int,
       M_point float
      ) 


   insert into #result (date,
       Left_Point,
       Right_Point,
       M_point)(
  SELECT
    CAST(pp.insertDate AS DATE) date,
    SUM(CASE WHEN pp.pointPosition = 'L' THEN pp.points END) AS leftpoint,
    SUM(CASE WHEN pp.pointPosition = 'R' THEN pp.points END) AS rightpoint,
    SUM(CASE WHEN pp.pointPosition = 'M' THEN pp.points END) AS mpoint   


  FROM dbo.payoutPoints AS pp
  WHERE pp.userid = @userId 
  GROUP BY CAST(pp.insertDate AS DATE))

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
                BEGIN
                    DROP TABLE #Temp;
                END;
  create table #Temp
  (date datetime,
  Left_Point int,
  Right_Point int,
  M_point int,
  amount float,
  netBal float,
  payoutBatchId int,
  tdsPercentage float,
  adminChargePercentage float,
  tds float,
  admincharge float,

  )
 --test
    insert into #Temp (
    date ,
  Left_Point ,
  Right_Point ,
  M_point ,
  amount ,
  netBal ,
  payoutBatchId ,
  tdsPercentage ,
  adminChargePercentage ,
  tds ,
  admincharge 
    ) select date,
     COALESCE(Left_Point , 0) as Left_Point,
     COALESCE(Right_Point , 0) as Right_Point,
     COALESCE(M_point , 0) as M_point,       
     COALESCE(totalbal , 0) as amount,
     COALESCE(UseBal , 0)   as netBal,
     payoutBatchId, 
     COALESCE(tdsPer , 0)  as tdsPercentage,
     COALESCE(adminchargePer , 0)  as adminChargePercentage,
     COALESCE(TotalTdsAmount , 0)   as tds, 
     COALESCE(TotalAdminAmount , 0) as admincharge
     from #result left join incentiveReport 
 on incentiveReport.dateTime=#result.date and incentiveReport.userid=@UserID 
  declare @startDate as datetime =(select top 1 DATE from #Temp)

  select * from #Temp 


  end
```